# How to retrieve time fields separately?

Tags: java, datetime

I convert current time to the integer formats using this code

```
 long x1=new Date().getTime();
 int x=(int) x1;
```

Now I want get the actual date values separately(Year,Month,Date,Hour,Minute) from the integer `int x`.

How can I do that?

Thank You(Please Guide me)

Comment: Normally we now use `LocalDate` in Java 8

Answer (score 3):

With java 8, you can easily manage that in [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)

```
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    int thisYear = today.getYear();
    int thisMonth = today.getMonthValue();
    int thisDay = today.getDayOfMonth();
    out.println(thisYear + "-" + thisMonth + "-" + thisDay);
```

But when you try to achieve more (hours, minutes, seconds), you then can turn to [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html)

```
    LocalDateTime curMoment = LocalDateTime.now();
    thisYear = curMoment.getYear();
    thisMonth = curMoment.getMonthValue();
    thisDay = curMoment.getDayOfMonth();
    int thisHour = curMoment.getHour();
    int thisMinute = curMoment.getMinute();
    int thisSecond = curMoment.getSecond();
    System.out.println(thisYear + "-" + thisMonth + "-" + thisDay + " " + thisHour + ":" + thisMinute + ":" + thisSecond);
```

And then the output will be:+

```
2018-7-4
2018-7-4 14:33:12
```

Comment: Perhaps you should suggest `LocalDateTime` as hours and minutes are also needed...?

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.currentTimeMillis() to return the current time in milliseconds  after that, you can do some math to figure out hours, minutes, and seconds.

```
    long totalMolilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long totalSeconds = totalMolilliseconds / 1000;
    long currentSeconds = totalSeconds % 60;
    long totalMinutes = totalSeconds / 60;
    long currentMinutes = totalMinutes % 60;
    long totalHours = totalMinutes / 60;
    long currentHours = totalHours % 24;
```

Comment: While I believe it works, it is not the recommended way. Better to use the library classes for self-explanatory and readable code that also convinces the reader that it is correct.